# Can anyone draw a chiasma in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams

I am trying to draw a two curved lines that form a chiasmata. I am imagining it would look like an 'X' that is composed of two CURVED lines such that it is wider than it is tall.

I also want to place four words, one at the end of each line. I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You wrote "I'm trying to draw...". What have you tried so far? Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Shouldn't it be called *chiasma*? I believe that *chiasmata* is plural.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[align=right,anchor=east] at(0,0) (a) {Tragedy};
        \node[below=1cm of a.east,anchor=east] (b) {Appearence};
        \node[right=2cm of a,anchor=west] (c) {Comedy};
        \node[below=1cm of c.west,anchor=west] (d) {Reality};
        \draw (a) edge[out=0, in=180] (d);
        \draw (b) edge[out=0, in=180] (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `bazier curves`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \node[align=right,anchor=east] at(0,0) (a) {Tragedy};
        \node[below=1cm of a.east,anchor=east] (b) {Appearence};
        \node[right=2cm of a,anchor=west] (c) {Comedy};
        \node[below=1cm of c.west,anchor=west] (d) {Reality};
        \draw (a.east) .. controls (2,-0.35) and (0,-0.65).. (d.west);
        \draw (b.east) .. controls (2,-0.65) and (0,-0.35).. (c.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And little cheating ;)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \node[align=right,anchor=east] at(0,0) (a) {Tragedy};
        \node[below=1cm of a.east,anchor=east] (b) {Appearence};
        \node[right=2cm of a,anchor=west] (c) {Comedy};
        \node[below=1cm of c.west,anchor=west] (d) {Reality};
        \draw[olive,thick] (a) edge[out=0,in=0,distance=1.335cm] (b);
        \draw[olive,thick] (c) edge[out=180,in=180,distance=1.335cm] (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the last change. If you are finding it difficult to handle bazier curve controls, this is just another short cut:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \node[align=right,anchor=east] at(0,0) (a) {Tragedy};
        \node[below=1cm of a.east,anchor=east] (b) {Appearence};
        \node[right=2cm of a,anchor=west] (c) {Comedy};
        \node[below=1cm of c.west,anchor=west] (d) {Reality};
        \path[draw=none] (a) -- (d) coordinate[midway] (m);
        \draw (a) edge[out=0,in=90] (m)
                            (m) edge[out=270,in=180] (d);
        \draw (b) edge[out=0,in=270] (m)
                            (m) edge[out=90,in=180] (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Jeez, no need to JPEG us like that. A simple PNG would absolutely have done it ;)

Comment: OP here. You are awesome! You not only saved my essay, but also I will now have the opportunity to practice using tikz and using \node and \draw. THANK YOU AGAIN!!!

Comment: @HarishKumar No, Christian didn't mean that :) He's talking about the image format.

Comment: Due to copy-paste `tragedy`: you missed the `reality` of `appearance`, hence it's `comedy` guess where ? :)

Comment: @HarishKumar Doesn't really matter, but it looks truly worse using JPEG (like that) rather than PNG (which doesn't loose quality).

Comment: Is it possible to have one line fly over the other the lines when crossing, like with the answer below using Metapost by Thruston ? I thought the fly over looked nice.

Comment: @Nasser It is possible: `\path[draw=none] (a) -- (d) node[midway,inner sep=0.5pt] (m){};
        \draw (a) edge[out=0,in=110] (m.110)
         (m.290) edge[out=290,in=180] (d);
        \draw (b) edge[out=0,in=250] (m.center)
         (m.center) edge[out=70,in=180] (c);`

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks for fixing it. Looks much better now :)

Comment: @HarishKumar I think it is "bezier curve" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Answer (score 16):

Since the curve has all the appearance of the `kappa curve`, we can plot the kappa curve with  `pst-plot`, given its polar equation (ρ = a/ tan θ):

```
        \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}

        \usepackage[svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
        \usepackage{pst-plot}

        \begin{document}

        \psset{unit=0.8cm}
        \begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
        \sffamily
        \psset{linewidth = 1pt, linecolor = IndianRed, plotpoints=200, plotstyle=curve, polarplot, algebraic, labelsep = 0.5em}
        \psclip{\pscircle[linestyle=none]{2.5}}%
         \psplot{0.5}{3}{1.5*cos(x)/sin(x)}
         \psplot{-0.5}{-3}{1.5*cos(x)/sin(x)}
         \endpsclip
         \uput[r](2.5; 32){Comedy} \uput[r](2.5; -32){Reality}
         \uput[l](-2.5; 32){Tragedy} \uput[l](-2.5; -32){Appearance}
         \end{pspicture}

        \end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: Kudos for genuine fidelity to OP's sample image. The examples that are "emphasizing the crossing" are changing the emphasized meaning of the diagram in the process. Yours preserves the original sense impeccably.

Comment: The above comment looks a lot sillier now that nearly everyone else has come around to the notion of respecting OP's spec drawing, but at the time you were swimming against the tide.

Answer (score 15):

With [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it):

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);
z0 = right scaled 60; 
z1 = -z3 = z0 rotated 30;
z4 = -z2 = z0 rotated -30;

path p[];
p1 = z2 {right} .. {right} z4;
p2 = z3 {right} .. {right} z1;
draw p2; undraw p1 withpen pencircle scaled 4; draw p1;

defaultfont := "phvr8r";
label.lft("Tragedy",z2);
label.lft("Appearance",z3);
label.rt("Comedy",z1);
label.rt("Reality",z4);

endfig;
end.
```

which tries to place an emphasis on the *crossing* by making one line fly over the other.

[image]

If you would rather keep some ambiguity and make the shape a little less chi-like, you could try bending the paths to the vertical where they cross and perhaps getting rid of the `undraw`, like this:

```
p1 = z2 {right} .. {down} origin .. {right} z4;
p2 = z3 {right} .. {up}   origin .. {right} z1;
draw p1; draw p2;
```

which changes the above picture to produce something more like the OP diagram

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Done by stacking and rotating text symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\def\stackalignment{r}\stackanchor[10pt]{Tragedy}{Appearance}
\abovebaseline[-10pt]{\scalebox{3}{\rotatebox{90}{$\bigcup$}\kern-.8pt\rotatebox{90}{$\bigcap$}}}
\def\stackalignment{l}\stackanchor[10pt]{Comedy}{Reality}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\makebox[3cm][r]{\rnode{ul}{Tragedy}}\hspace{3cm}\rnode{ur}{Comedy}\\[1.25cm]
\makebox[3cm][r]{\rnode{ll}{Appearence}}\hspace{3cm}\rnode{lr}{Reality}
\nccurve[nodesep=5pt,angleB=180]{ul}{lr}
\nccurve[nodesep=5pt,angleB=180,border=2pt]{ll}{ur}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Warming up with PSTricks.

### Option 1

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=3cm,nodesep=2mm,arm=1.3,linearc=1]
    [mcol=r]Tragedy & [mcol=l]Comedy\\
    [mcol=r]Appearence & [mcol=l]Appearence
    \ncdiag{1,1}{2,1}
    \ncdiag[angle=180]{1,2}{2,2}
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 2

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=3cm,nodesep=5pt,angleB=180]
    [mcol=r]Tragedy & [mcol=l]Comedy\\
    [mcol=r]Appearence & [mcol=l]Appearence
    \nccurve{1,1}{2,2}
    \nccurve[border=2pt]{2,1}{1,2}
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 3

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=3cm,nodesep=5pt,angleB=180]
    [mcol=r]Tragedy & [mcol=l]Comedy\\
    [mcol=r]Appearence & [mcol=l]Appearence
    \ncdiag{1,1}{2,2}
    \ncdiag[border=2pt]{2,1}{1,2}
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Due to copy-paste `tragedy`: you missed the `reality` of `appearance`, hence it's `comedy` guess where ? :)

Comment: @texenthusiast: It was copied from Harish Kumar's answer. See his edit history for the details.

Comment: yes, i know. `appearance` was twice and missed the `reality` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162475/can-anyone-draw-a-chiasma-in-latex/162560?noredirect=1#comment372628_162490

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `xypic`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xypic}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}\xymatrix@R=5mm@C=2cm{
        \txt{Tragedy} \ar@{- }@(r,l)[dr] & \txt{Comedy}\\
        \txt{Appearance} \ar@{- }@(r,l)[ur] & \txt{Reality}
    }\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

`@R=5mm` and `@C=2cm` set the column and row sizes. `@{- }` removes arrow heads and `@(r,l)` gives the lines their curvature. You can do a lot more with [`xypic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic).

[image: example output]